# Maximum Matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I have a graph G with 13 vertices and I need to find a maximum matching and then prove it. If I find a matching containing 6 edges or 12 out of the 13 vertices can I say it's maximum because I cannot add any edges because there is only one vertex remaining as my proof?

Edit.
I have this graph and I need to determine a maximum matching and then prove it. I found a matching containing 12 out of the 13 vertices.Can I say it's
maximum because I cannot add any other edge as my proof.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the graph and I tried to simplify my question

Comment: If you find a matching containing six edges, then of course this is the maximum matching.

Comment: I found one with six edges. I was just wondering if I could use that as my proof or I would have to proof it with any  other way more complicated as this is an easy proof. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that in this case you don't need anything else.

Comment: Suppose there's a larger matching. Then that matching contains at least 14 distinct vertices, but the graph only has 13. Contradiction.

Comment: @HaydnGwyn We don't need a contradiction. We can argue directly that seven edges require at least fourteen vertices so the maximum matching for a graph with thirteen vertices must be less than or equal to six. Therefore, upon exhibiting a matching of size six, we are done.

Comment: I'd call these matchings *maximal* rather than *maximum* since there can be (generally are) more than one in any given graph.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Usually the distinction between "maximal" and "maximum" is drawn differently: a matching is maximal if we cannot add any edges to it, even if it is smaller than a maximum matching. (Although personally I do not like any terminology distinction that depends on a single syllable.)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot add any edges, then it is maximal. But if you have all but one edges and you can't add the remaining edge, as in your case, then it is maximum as well as maximal (because the only way to make it larger is to add the remaining edge).